# Import a list of string from another file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would create a class with a list of string in flutter on a another file and import this file to a main file that I am working.... for example:

```
class OrderDetails {

  final email = 'Email';
  final name = 'Mario';
  final city = 'Milano';

}
```

have this class into a file called details.dart
and import these strings to another main file

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the question is to retrieve these string above, into another file without write these string into the direct file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 details.dart

class OrderDetails {
  static final email = 'Email';
  static final name = 'Mario';
  static final city = 'Milano';
}
```

import this file to that file where you want to use this file using

```
 import '/your_file_path/details.dart';
```

now use those value like this

```
 OrderDetails.email etc
```